# Tried to install gromacs 5.1.1 via homebrew, all commands are not found

Tags: macos, homebrew

I've tried to install gromacs on my system (10.11.5) via homebrew.  The command I used was `brew install gromacs` and it appears to have worked fine; gromacs is in my `usr/bin/Cellar`, and shows up when I run `brew list`.

But, when I try to actually run any gromacs command, I just get a command not found error.  When I try to run `man gromacs` it tells me there is no manual entry for gromacs; I get man entries as normal for other brew packages I'm using.

`brew doctor` output is pasted below, but nothing in there means anything to me.  I'd appreciate your perspectives on how to make this work, or on what other information I might need to include.

I wonder if I need to modify my PATH, but if so I don't know how to do that or what to modify it to.

Cheers

**brew doctor output after this**

`Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.`

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
    /usr/local/include/fakepq.h
    /usr/local/include/fakesql.h
    /usr/local/include/itcl.h
    /usr/local/include/itcl2TclOO.h
    /usr/local/include/itclDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/itclInt.h
    /usr/local/include/itclIntDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/itclMigrate2TclCore.h
    /usr/local/include/itclTclIntStubsFcn.h
    /usr/local/include/mysqlStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/odbcStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/pqStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/tcl.h
    /usr/local/include/tclDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclOO.h
    /usr/local/include/tclOODecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclPlatDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclThread.h
    /usr/local/include/tclTomMath.h
    /usr/local/include/tclTomMathDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbc.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbcDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbcInt.h
    /usr/local/include/tk.h
    /usr/local/include/tkDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tkPlatDecls.h

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libfftw3f.la
    /usr/local/lib/libfftw3f_threads.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
    /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself, so I'm posting the answer in case anyone else has this problem.

The answer was that gromacs has changed since the version I used most recently, and the commands I was used to no longer exist.  For example, the `g_energy` command now runs as `gmx energy`.

If you are also having this problem, `gmx help commands` should give you a list of what the commands are now.

Thanks for reading this!